# remove zero's at the beginning of a string of numbers VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of numbers and I need to remove the leading zero's from each cell in the column if the numbers begin with zero's.

Comment: Format the cells as numbers and not text, and Excel will do this for you.

Comment: You didn't try something like `if isnumeric(activecell) then activecell.Value=cdbl(activecell.Value)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    with .columns(1)
        .numberformat = "General"
        .texttocolumns destination:=.cells(1), _
                       datatype:=xlFixedWidth, fieldinfo:=Array(0, 1)
    end with
end with
```

Comment: [The first element is the column number (1-based)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) so why does yours start with 0?

Comment: @findwindow  -Thanks for catching that. Fixed above now. Wrote that off the top of my head; I must have been day-dreaming of footnotes.

Comment: @findwindow - You only read half of the description for the **FieldInfo** parameter of the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx). You missed *'When the data is delimited, ...'*. This is an **xlFixedWidth** 'split' (not actually a split at all) and the **0** refers to the start of the fixed width position of the split. A single two element array of **0** and a [xlColumnDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241018%28v=office.12%29.aspx) means only one column; no split at all.

Comment: Yea I didn't really understand what was meant by `xlFixedWidth` either XD The nomenclature is really poor because width to me suggests column width but it means number of columns? Seems `xlFixedWidth` is redundant if you can just indicate with 0 in the array? Thank you for explaining <3 Guess I upvote even without footnote...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can figure out how to iterate through each cell so I'm not going to demonstrate that in the code example below. This will do the trick. Replace A4 with each cell you need to process.

```
Dim My_Number As String
Dim i As Integer
My_Number = Range("A4")
For i = 1 To Len(My_Number) - 1
    If InStr(1, My_Number, "0") = 1 Then
        My_Number = Right(My_Number, Len(My_Number) - 1)
    Else
        Range("A4") = My_Number
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Instr is looking for a zero in the fist position of the string. If if finds a zero then the next line writes all the string characters besides the first one(the zero) to the cell.

Comment: What if there's more than 1 leading zero?

Comment: Hey, I updated the code section above. You essentially just loop through the string and examine the first character for a zero. There's really probably 100 ways to do this.

Comment: That's what Dan did above?

Answer (score 0):

If converting to numbers isn't a viable solution for you then this UDF will work:

```
Function StripLeadingZeros(MyString As String)
Dim X As Long
For X = 1 To Len(MyString)
    If Left(MyString, 1) = "0" Then
        MyString = Right(MyString, Len(MyString) - 1)
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next
StripLeadingZeros = MyString
End Function
```